# request for member 's' in something not a structure or union

Tags: c

I'm trying to use an array of structs and everytime I try to assign a value to any struct, it gives me this error:

```
request for member 's' in something not a structure or union
```

My struct:

```
struct {
    char s;
    int lineNum;
} item;
```

I'm declaring it this way:

```
struct item * stack[100];
```

And then:

```
/* both lines gives me the error */
    stack[0].s = 'a';
    stack[0].lineNum = 1;
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Tried that and now the error changed to: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

Comment: Just FYI: your struct construct defines an object named `item`. Its type is a two field structure without a tag or alias (`typedef`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need this:

```
struct item {
    char s;
    int lineNum;
} ;
...
struct item * stack[100];
...
stack[0]->s = 'a';
stack[0]->lineNum = 1;
```

but beware: you need to allocate memory for each item in `stack`. `stack` contains 100 pointers to `struct item`s, but each of these pointers contains garbage (they all point to invalid memory).

For each element in `stack` you need to allocate memory like this `stack[n] = malloc(sizeof struct item)`.

Answer (score 8):

You do not have a `struct item`.

`stack` is an array of 100 pointer to an as yet undefined struct.

Try

```
struct item {
    char s;
    int lineNum;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`struct item stack[100]` is what you want for your code that follows. What you have is an array of pointers, each of which if you wish to use, you will need to allocate, before your declaration.

Comment: That plus @pmg's answer

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined `struct item`. You currently have a single variable named `item` of an anonymous `struct`. It appears you forgot to include the `typedef`:

```
typedef struct { ... } a_t; // can use "a_t" as type.

struct a { ... }; // can use "struct a" as type.

typedef struct a { ... } a_t; // can use "struct a" or "a_t" as type.
```

Answer (score 0):

`stacks` is not an array of `item`s, it's an array of **pointers to `item`s**, so you need to dereference them before attempting to use them:

```
(*(stack[0])).s = 'a';
(*(stack[0])).lineNum = 1;
```